# How to make a list of n lists shuffled in order (in the most pythonic way possible)?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Having this:

```
a = 12
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

What is the most pythonic way to convert it into this?:

```
[12, 1, 12, 2, 12, 3]
```

Comment: Can you try to be clearer in what you're trying to achieve? Are you just inserting a before every element in b?

Comment: You want to alternate between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
>>> a
12
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[[a] + [x] for x in b])
[12, 1, 12, 2, 12, 3]
```

Comment: All answers are right, but this one is the biest IMHO. Just note that in Python 3 you need to `from functools import reduce` before.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to alternate between `a` and elements of `b`. You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and `zip` , Example -

```
>>> a = 12
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> [i for item in zip(cycle([a]),b) for i in item]
[12, 1, 12, 2, 12, 3]
```

Comment: Can do it without `itertools` also using `[i for item in zip([a]*len(b),b) for i in item]`. But itertools is a great idea here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.repeat` to create an iterable with the length of `b` then use `zip` to put its item alongside the items of `a` and at last use `chain.from_iterable` function to concatenate the pairs:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat,chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(repeat(a,len(b)),b)))
[12, 1, 12, 2, 12, 3]
```

Also without `itertools` you can use following trick :

```
>>> it=iter(b)
>>> [next(it) if i%2==0 else a for i in range(len(b)*2)]
[1, 12, 2, 12, 3, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it
# fillvalue, which is **a** in this case, will be zipped in tuples with,
# elements of b as long as the length of b permits.
# chain.from_iterable will then flatten the tuple list into a single list
list(it.chain.from_iterable(zip_longest([], b, fillvalue=a)))

[12, 1, 12, 2, 12, 3]
```

Comment: Just dumping code without an explanation doesn't help OP or future readers. Please add an explanation to your code.